# Inside the homes of ... is / was

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I am wondering whether the tenses are not quite good in the following:

> Inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs **is** where house poles **were** found.

As you can see, there are both present and past tense forms.

Also, what's the difference between the above and the following?

> Inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs **was** where house poles **were** found.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no reason why you can't mix tenses in some constructions. This is one of them. (I'm not providing an actual answer because I don't know how to properly express the difference—or why you sometimes can and sometimes can't mix tenses.)

Comment: You could just avoid the problem with the active voice: "House poles were found inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs."

Answer (score 1):

> Inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs **was** where house poles **were** found.

This is semantically the same as:

> (1) Inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs, house poles were found

So, normally you'd want to use **was**.

But this is not to say that **is** is impossible, if you'd like to convey a slightly different meaning than (1).

Using **is** instead of **was** makes sure that the sentence is valid not only in the past but also in the present.

Similarly, you could use both **is** and **was** in the following:

> It **is**/**was** inside the homes of high-ranking chiefs that house poles **were** found.